# PHP Form Handling Error

Tags: php, browser

> my action.php site does not keep the input (form handling). here is my
>   acion.php.

```
<?php>
echo $_GET['fn'];?><br>
<?php>
echo $_GET["ln"];?>
<?php>
echo $_GET["e-mail"];?>
<?php>
echo $_GET["message"];?>
```

> this is the form in main html site

```
<form action="action.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="fn"  placeholder="Ad"></input>
<br>
<input type="text" name="ln"  placeholder="Soy Ad"></input><br>
<input type="text" name="e-mail"  placeholder="e-Mail"></input><br>
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">Yorumunuz.</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="gonder" value="Gönder"></input>
</form>
```

> secondary do i have to put " or ' ----> $_GET["fn"] or  $_GET['fn']

Comment: you don't need  `>` after  `<?php ` . it can be <?php
echo $_GET['fn'];?> . other one both single quotes and double quotes are okay.

Comment: What's your actual problem the question is really confusing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you looking for this:

```
<form action="action.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="fn" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['fn']) && $_GET['fn']!=""){echo $_GET['fn'];} ?>"  placeholder="Ad">
  </input>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="ln" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['ln']) && $_GET['ln']!=""){echo $_GET['ln'];} ?>" placeholder="Soy Ad">
  </input>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="e-mail" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['e-mail']) && $_GET['e-mail']!=""){echo $_GET['e-mail'];} ?>" placeholder="e-Mail">
  </input>
  <br>
  <textarea name="message" rows="10" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message']!=""){echo $_GET['message'];} ?>" cols="30">Yorumunuz.</textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="gonder" value="Gönder">
  </input>
</form>
<?php
echo $_GET["fn"]."<br />";
echo $_GET["ln"]."<br />";
echo $_GET["e-mail"]."<br />";
echo $_GET["message"]."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: i have no enough repudation

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error:

```
<?php>
echo $_GET['fn'];?><br>
<?php>
echo $_GET["ln"];?>
<?php>
echo $_GET["e-mail"];?>
<?php>
echo $_GET["message"];?>
```

should be

```
<?php
echo $_GET["fn"];?><br>
<?php
echo $_GET["ln"];?>
<?php
echo $_GET["e-mail"];?>
<?php
echo $_GET["message"];?>
```

It dosent metter in this case if you are using ' Or " it is metter
in cases that you want to echo value of a string:

```
$str = "test";
echo "test is $str"; // will echo test is test
echo 'test is $str'; // will echo test is $str
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: this is the php opening tag <?php  you wrote <?php>